# Applying Basename to CSS class with PHP but error with index page

Tags: php, css

I've search Google and the site, but can't find an answer to this, though I imagine there must be one out there. If you can answer or point me in the direction of an answer, I'd be very grateful.

Basically, I'm trying to use PHP to apply a CSS class to my container, and it works on all pages except the homepage.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

URL: www.example.com/alpha/
Class: alpha

URL: www.example.com/alpha/bravo
Class: alpha

URL: www.example.com/bravo/
Class: bravo

URL: www.example.com/bravo/charlie
Class: bravo

That's all working, but on the homepage, it's not. The code I'm using is:

```
    <div id="container" class="<?= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php") ?>">
```

But on the homepage it outputs it as the class name, presumably because it hasn't got anything to follow it. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Since there is nothing there, it wont work (as you've stated). I guess you can just use an if statement. `if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){ echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];}else{echo "index";}` or shorthand: `class ='<?php (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ? basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) : 'index').'.php';`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't work, but I think that's because the index page is actually written in Ruby (sorry! I forgot to mention that rather important fact!).

I've got round it by doing the following:

I placed this in the header:

```
<?php
$url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php")
?>
```

And then set this for the container:

```
<div id="container" class="<?php echo $url ?>">
```

It's a bit messy, because on the Ruby page it outputs the class exactly like that in the source, but at least I don't have any characters flowing on to the page like I did before.

I hope this helps someone in the future. Feel free to post any alternative methods below, especially if it tidies up the class output in non-php pages.

Cheers!